# npm start in a react-app showing js heap out of memory

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, memory

I am running npm start but it is showing js heap out of memory. What can I do to solve this?

I tried using `node --max-old-space-size=8000` but this also wont work.

Comment: if your React app needs that much memory, something has gone _ridiculously_ wrong. Start reducing your code until it no longer crashes, than look at the last bit you just removed. For more information on this process, see the article on creating a [mcve].

Comment: maybe than I didnt do it right.. Can you tell me how to start all over again?

Comment: I have no idea what you're actually working on, so I couldn't tell you, short of "start with https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html in a new dir, and see where that takes you".